# Python String Binary Concatenation Error: Unicode Decode Exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, concatenation

I'm facing an issue while trying to concatenate strings with gzipped content

```
content = "Some Long Content"
out = StringIO.StringIO() 
with gzip.GZipFile(fileobj=out, mode='w') as f:
    f.write(content)
gzipped_content = out.getvalue() 

part1 = 'Something'
part2 = 'SomethingElse'
complete_content = part1 + part2 + gzipped_content
```

During Execution, this causes a UnicodeDecodeError

```
complete_content = part1 + part2 + gzipped_content 
exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm unable to figure out why an ascii decode is required for String Concatenation.

Is there a way around to make the concatenation happen?

Comment: This is my output[python 2.7.12-1]: SomethingSomethingElse;S)X�
                             ��MU���KWp��+I�+o��6

Comment: I've been getting inconsistent results with this. Sometimes the output is just as same as yours while at others, I end up with the above scenario. The issue seems intermittent and I'm unable to figure out why

Comment: When I convert your code snippet to a complete program it works perfectly (http://ideone.com/WBI6pf). Please reduce your program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste the entire short program into your question. Please include both the expected and the actual output of your program. See [mcve] for more information.